# curl scrape page, not showing search entries (no js/cookie issue)

Tags: php, cookies, curl, scrape

I'm trying to scrape a website using curl and php.
Now i have to login, that isn't the problem.

I login using cookies and than navigate to a list with products.
These products are just printed with php on their site. So not with javascript.

But when i use curl it says the brand/search couldn't be found(No Results Returned).
I changed the referrer and host.

How could they detect this and is there a possible way to 'bypass' it?
I got a csv file with their products(got it from them) but not with ammount and price and description.
So i want to fill that part in myself.

Here is my script:

```
include('brands.php');

$request = array(
    'username'=>'******',
    'pass'=>'*********',
    'submit'=>'',
    'part-submit'=>'',
    'referlink'=>'',
    'remember'=>1
);
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.website.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($request));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $array[$_GET['k']]."&rpp=100");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: website.com'));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.website.com/linecard.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ));
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($curl_errno > 0) {
    die("cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n");
}

echo $response;
```

Thanks in advance!

ps. removed the offocial website, will provide when needed. for their security and google hits

Comment: In my bounty i set vURL i meant cURL offcourse!

Comment: Can you try to get some extra debugging output using the ways [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/1419007)? It may make it easier to diagnose your problem. — Also, can you give the headers for the steps you took to successfully perform a search in the browser and the headers for the steps that failed in cURL? Also, I see that `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` for the `Host` header uses `website.com` without `www.`, but your `URL` and `Referer` [sic] do have the `www` part.

Comment: You need to provide a test-url, a test-login and the other missing test-data with your question, otherwise this can not be answered as it can not be reproduced. On my computer curl has not problem to do HTTP requests to websites. There is no magic to make it working on your computer, too, just technical details that need to be looked into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is actually fairly simple..
My connection to the site is closed every curl request.
I don't want that, so the solution to this problem is removing the `curl_close ($ch);` after i login into the website.

Than everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure...maybe im sayng a stupid thing...

anyway, the url end with / and http_build_query will create var=value&var2=value...

so the request would be: "http://www.website.com/var=value&var2=value

so is incorrect....

the url should be http://www.website.com/search_page.php?

Have a nice day

Antonio